# Book series where Earth has been invaded by matriarchal blue or green skinned aliens

Tags: story-identification

If I remember correctly, each book in the series had a name that starts with "Re", e.g. "Rebellion", "Retribution", "Restitution", "Restoration".

The earth had been invaded by a race of very human-like blue-skinned (or green-?) aliens. These aliens had a matriarchal society (basically all the traditional gender roles were swapped), largely because the women were strong telepaths, but the men were much weaker in that regard. However, the lead character, Jason, is immune to their telepathy (discovered later to be due to his ancient ancestral heritage, which involves other perks as well), and he leads a (primarily) economic rebellion to take back the earth. Jason is also a brilliant engineer and creative, so he's able to figure out tricky ways to make life hard (expensive) on the aliens, without creating all-out war.

Telepathy and space travel play significant roles in the story. I think the strongest telepaths (who had (almost) all died out) were from the Karenin (sp?) clan.

Does anyone recognize the stories? Can you direct me to where I can find them?

Comment: Same question as posted here: https://www.remindask.com/questions/315673/i-need-help-finding-a-book-series

Comment: That site is fairly obviously scraping SE sites for its own questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it! It is the [Subjugation](http://www.weavespinner.net/worlds_of_fel.htm#Subjugation) series by Fel (James Galloway).

> Subjugation is a story that centers around Jason Fox and Jyslin Shaddale.  The Faey, an alien telepathic race, has taken control of Earth and are using it as a farming colony to supply food for their empire.  Jason is a college student who is learning faey technology, but is upset with the faey and their treatment of Earth.  Along the way, Jason meets a fiery red head name Jyslin, who takes a fancy to him and will not take no for an answer.  There is a problem though.  Jyslin is a Faey Imperial Marine.  And, marines are not easily deterred. . .

By the way, I was wrong about the naming. The titles are (1) *Subjugation*, (2) *Insurrection*, (3) *Unification*, (4) *Tribulation*, (5) *Secession*, (6) *Inception*, (7) *Conviction*.

Comment: Thank you for posting and accepting your own answer. It's very helpful to future searchers.